# How to get order Grand Total from information about order's items (products)?

Tags: database, magento-1, sales-order, sql, grand-total

I'm building a custom report on the basis of database.

I need to know how to get 'Grand Total' that is in 'sales/order' (in other words `sales_flat_order`) table by order items (from 'sales/order_item', `sales_flat_order_item` table).

I need a formula to get this value using the database and not using Magento methods.

I am building **MySQL query**

Am I right when I say that

```
base_grand_total =  (IFNULL(base_total_canceled,0)) +  (IFNULL(base_hidden_tax_amount,0) - IFNULL(base_hidden_tax_refunded,0)) + IFNULL(base_total_offline_refunded,0) + IFNULL(base_total_online_refunded,0) +  ( IFNULL(base_subtotal,0) - IFNULL(base_subtotal_canceled,0) - IFNULL(base_subtotal_refunded,0)) + (IFNULL(base_tax_amount,0) - IFNULL(base_tax_canceled,0) - IFNULL(base_tax_refunded,0)) + (IFNULL(base_shipping_amount,0) - IFNULL(base_shipping_canceled,0) - IFNULL(base_shipping_refunded,0)) + (IFNULL(base_discount_amount,0) - IFNULL(base_discount_canceled,0) - IFNULL(base_discount_refunded,0)) ?
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL query ? if so please post here

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry. I had to immediately indicate this

Comment: can you post that query here ? Basic query should look like: SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` as sfo INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` as sfoi ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id WHERE sfoi.order_id = 42

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can write sql query. I need to know how to calculate base_grand_total using Subtotal, Tax, Shipping and other..

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the order_entity_id and get the grand total value

```
function get_order_details($order_entity_id)
{
$getsales = mysql_query("SELECT grand_total FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE `entity_id`='$order_entity_id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($getsales) == 1)
{
return mysql_fetch_object($getsales);
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($getsales) > 1)
{
return $getsales;
}
else
return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need calculate "grand total" by order items. I group products according to different parameters, so I need exactly the formula for calculating this value. I can use table `sales_flat_order_item` and some values (such as 'shipping...') from `sales_flat_order`

Comment: A more specific question - how to calculate the 'grand total' on the base of the other fields of the table `sales_flat_order` ?